# Wordpress override default status on CPT

Tags: wordpress, status

Is there any way we can override the default post statuses without a plugin?

instead of 'published', 'Pending review' and 'Draft' I want something like 'New', 'In progress' and 'Completed'

Answer (score 0):

you could always change the post status and echo out your custom value:

```
if ( get_post_status ( $ID ) == 'published' ) { 
 echo 'New';
} elseif ( get_post_status ( $ID ) == 'pending' ) {
 echo 'In progress';
}
```

WordPress [get_post_status function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_status/) to learn more